# Trying to add a class for clicked elements but if statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
<div>
<div class=category> Birthdays </div>
<div class=category> Anniversaries </div>
<div class=category> Newborns </div>
<div class=category> Weddings </div>
</div>

<ul>
<li class="product-filter-items">Birthdays</li>
<li class="product-filter-items">Weddings</li>
<li class="product-filter-items">Newborns</li>
<li class="product-filter-items">Anniversaries</li>
</ul>

<script>
    let proCatList = document.querySelectorAll(".category")
    
    let proFilterItems = document.querySelectorAll(".product-filter-items")        
    
    for(let i = 0; i < proFilterItems.length; i++){
    
        proFilterItems[i].addEventListener("click" , function(){        
        
        if (proCatList[i].textContent.toUpperCase().replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ').trim() == proFilterItems[i].textContent.toUpperCase().replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ').trim()  ){
    
            proFilterItems[i].classList.add("active-filter")
            console.log("Class Added")
            }
    })  
    
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to add a class based on a click event. What I am trying to do is if classname, category and product-filter-items are equal then it should add a classname called active-filter on click. Can anyone point out why this statement does not recognise the textContent of proCatList?

Comment: Can you please add more details what you are trying to achieve. Its confusing, looks like you are checking if the order of the category is same as the order of the product-filetr-item, then you are adding a class 'active-filter' to the product-filter-items

Answer (score 0):

The iteration param `i` can't be used in the event handler. Therefor you could use the index of the clicked element, which you can call with `this`.

For getting the index, you can use the following small function:

```js
const getIndex = elem => [...elem.parentNode.children].indexOf(elem);
```

**Working example:**

```js
let proCatList = document.querySelectorAll(".category");
let proFilterItems = document.querySelectorAll(".product-filter-items");

/* small function for getting the index */
const getIndex = elem => [...elem.parentNode.children].indexOf(elem);

for (let i = 0; i < proFilterItems.length; i++) {
  proFilterItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    const elem_index = getIndex(this);
    
    if (proCatList[elem_index].textContent.toUpperCase().replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ').trim() == this.textContent.toUpperCase().replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ').trim()) {
      this.classList.add("active-filter");
      console.log("Class Added");
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=category> Birthdays </div>
  <div class=category> Anniversaries </div>
  <div class=category> Newborns </div>
  <div class=category> Weddings </div>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="product-filter-items">Birthdays</li>
  <li class="product-filter-items">Weddings</li>
  <li class="product-filter-items">Newborns</li>
  <li class="product-filter-items">Anniversaries</li>
</ul>
```